# VB.NET: Too many connections

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, ado.net, connection

While testing my program, an error popped up saying, "Too many connections" when I tried to log in an another user.

I need to fix it so that the connections aren't left open to time out on their own, so that it runs perfectly.

```
 Private Sub addstub()
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
        SQL = "SELECT count(*) from remaining_ham where Stub=@stub and Emp_No LIKE '%" & txtid.Text & "%'"
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stub", txtclaim.Text)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim", "CLAIMED")
            Command.CommandText = SQL
            connection.Open()
            Dim count As Integer = Command.ExecuteScalar

            If count = 1 Then
                MsgBox("PROCESSING")
                Using connection2 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                    SQL = "Select count(*) from  remaining_ham where status='CLAIMED' and Stub='" & txtclaim.Text & "' and Emp_No LIKE'%" & txtid.Text & "%' "
                    Using command2 As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)
                        connection2.Open()
                        Dim i1 As Integer = command2.ExecuteScalar()
                        If i1 = 1 Then
                            MsgBox("ALREADY CLAIMED")
                        Else
                            Using connection3 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                                SQL = "Select Stub,Total,Brickham,Jamon,Fiesta,status from remaining_ham where Stub='" & txtclaim.Text & "'  and Emp_No LIKE'%" & txtid.Text & "%' "
                                Using myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection)
                                    Dim table = New DataSet
                                    myAdapter.Fill(table)

                                    txtbrick.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Brickham").ToString
                                    txtjamon.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Jamon").ToString
                                    txtfiesta.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Fiesta").ToString
                                    txttotal.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Total").ToString

                                    If MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE?" + Environment.NewLine + "Stub No: " + txtid.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Brickham: " + txtbrick.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Jamon De Bola: " + txtjamon.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Fiesta Ham: " + txtfiesta.Text, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                                        'MsgBox("TAMA")
                                        jam = CDbl(txtjamon.Text)
                                        rmham = CDbl(txtremjamon.Text)
                                        txtremjamon.Text = (rmham - jam).ToString
                                        Dim dbjam = Format(CDbl(txtremjamon.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbjam = "" Then
                                            dbjam = 0
                                        End If

                                        brk = CDbl(txtbrick.Text)
                                        rembrk = CDbl(txtrembrick.Text)
                                        txtrembrick.Text = (rembrk - brk).ToString
                                        Dim dbbrick = Format(CDbl(txtrembrick.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbbrick = "" Then
                                            dbbrick = 0
                                        End If

                                        fiesta = CDbl(txtfiesta.Text)
                                        rmfiesta = CDbl(txtremfiesta.Text)
                                        txtremfiesta.Text = (rmfiesta - fiesta).ToString
                                        Dim dbfiesta = Format(CDbl(txtremfiesta.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbfiesta = "" Then
                                            dbfiesta = 0
                                        End If
                                        total = CDbl(txttotal.Text)
                                        rmtotal = CDbl(txtremtotal.Text)
                                        txtremtotal.Text = (rmtotal - total).ToString
                                        Dim dbtotal = Format(CDbl(txtremtotal.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbtotal = "" Then
                                            dbtotal = 0
                                        End If

                                        Using connection4 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                                            SQL = "UPDATE order_ham SET rem_brick='" & dbbrick & "', rem_jam='" & dbjam & "', rem_fiesta='" & dbfiesta & "', rem_total='" & dbtotal & "' where Emp_No=" & txtid.Text & "  "
                                            Using command3 As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection4)
                                                connection4.Open()
                                                Dim i As Integer = command3.ExecuteNonQuery
                                                If i = 0 Then
                                                    MsgBox("WRONG")
                                                    Exit Sub
                                                Else
                                                    ' MsgBox("RIGHT")
                                                    Using connection5 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                                                        Dim date1 As Date = Date.Today
                                                        SQL = "UPDATE remaining_ham SET status='CLAIMED',ddate='" & DateTime.Now & "' where Stub='" + txtclaim.Text + "' and Emp_No LIKE '%" + txtid.Text + "%'  "
                                                        Using command4 As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection5)
                                                            connection5.Open()
                                                            Dim a As Integer = command4.ExecuteNonQuery
                                                            connection5.Close()
                                                            If a = 0 Then
                                                                MsgBox("not claim: ERROR ")
                                                                Exit Sub
                                                            Else
                                                                MsgBox("SUCCESS")
                                                                Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection5)
                                                                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                                                                    da.Fill(dt)
                                                                    MetroGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
                                                                    MetroGrid1.Rows.Clear()
                                                                    MetroGrid3.DataSource = Nothing
                                                                    MetroGrid3.Rows.Clear()
                                                                    loadRemainingHam()
                                                                    remainingorder()
                                                                    txtclaim.Focus()
                                                                End Using


                                                            End If


                                                        End Using
                                                    End Using

                                                End If
                                            End Using
                                        End Using




                                    Else
                                        MsgBox("CANCELLED")
                                    End If

                                End Using
                            End Using
                        End If

                    End Using
                End Using
            Else
                MsgBox("ERROR")
            End If

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Thank you for those who will answer.

Comment: Close your connections, currently you are not and hence your problems. After you call the database and get what you need call `close`... Also IMO this is bad design, seperate your calls into functions, this way logic can be separated and less error prone, there's no need to have nested calls the way you are now...

Comment: ok i will and ill get back to you zaggler for the update. thank you for your rseponse

Comment: tried closing right before the closing of using statement and it says the connection must be open and valid on the command executenonquery

Comment: Welcome, if you have those in a `Using` block the object is only disposed, your connection at this point is still hanging on. Call close on them to allocate them back into the connection pool to be used.

Comment: No call close after your `Execute` statements or `Fill`. Anytime you call the db exactly after call close on the connection.

Comment: also tried callling close right after the statement after connection open and it says connection must be valid and open

Comment: i have these working on some accounts but then I just encountered it today

Comment: For example this line `connection.Open()
            Dim count As Integer = Command.ExecuteScalar`... It should be `connection.Open()
            Dim count As Integer = Command.ExecuteScalar connection.Close()` Don't call close after you open it otherwise you can't make the db call...

Comment: yes that's what I did

Comment: but then it insists that the connection are close

Comment: And it says it must be open?

Comment: yes it says it must be valid and open

Comment: Have u put a breakpoint on the first connection open and stepped through?

Comment: like it was working all the time for like 2wks for my testing and then these came up too many connection

Comment: ill try debugging it

Comment: Try `MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools()` or add `Pooling=false` parameter to your connection string

Comment: i think there is wrong with our server. for the other running program with the same connection stating too many connections

Comment: You should definitely be looking at closing connections once you are done with them. I would also look into separate functions as @Zaggler has said. Your code will be much cleaner that way. Currently you're nesting right down and you don't need to. It's very difficult to debug currently.

Comment: @Jinx88909, currently my db server is experiencing a problem and i don't know why. it just said it has too many connection where in there are many programs that are connected to my server but it seems malfunctioning right now. I transfer my data to other db server and it seems fine.

Comment: Why are you using more than one connection at all???  As long as it is the same server etc, you can perform more than one action on a single connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform multiple commands/actions with 1 connection.

You could try something like this:

```
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
connection.Open()
Dim SQL as String = "SELECT count(*) from remaining_ham where Stub=@stub and Emp_No LIKE '%" & txtid.Text & "%'"

Using ObjCommand As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)
    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stub", txtclaim.Text)
    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim", "CLAIMED")
    ObjCommand.CommandText = SQL

    Dim count As Integer = Command.ExecuteScalar

    If count = 1 Then

        MsgBox("PROCESSING")
        SQL = "Select count(*) from  remaining_ham where status='CLAIMED' and Stub='" & txtclaim.Text & "' and Emp_No LIKE'%" & txtid.Text & "%' "

        Using ObjCommand2 As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)

            Dim i1 As Integer = command2.ExecuteScalar()

            If i1 = 1 Then

                MsgBox("ALREADY CLAIMED")

            Else

                SQL = "Select Stub,Total,Brickham,Jamon,Fiesta,status from remaining_ham where Stub='" & txtclaim.Text & "'  and Emp_No LIKE'%" & txtid.Text & "%' "

                Using myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection)

                    //code here 

                End Using

            End If

        End Using

    End If

End Using
connection.Close()
connection.Dispose()
```

Answer (score -1):

What is the database of this program? can you please add `;pooling=false` at the end of your mysqlconnection like this

`server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;pooling=false`

and try it

Answer (score -1):

You have way to many queries inside of queries. Try to remove as much as possible. Here's an example with the first one.
You should close the connections as soon as possible.

```
Private Sub addstub()

    '*** GET THE COUNT, CLOSE THE CONNECTION, NOT NEEDED ANYMORE.
    Dim count As Integer

    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
        SQL = "SELECT count(*) from remaining_ham where Stub=@stub and Emp_No LIKE '%" & txtid.Text & "%'"
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stub", txtclaim.Text)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim", "CLAIMED")
            Command.CommandText = SQL
            connection.Open()
            count = Command.ExecuteScalar
        End Using
    End Using

            If count = 1 Then
                MsgBox("PROCESSING")
                Using connection2 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                    SQL = "Select count(*) from  remaining_ham where status='CLAIMED' and Stub='" & txtclaim.Text & "' and Emp_No LIKE'%" & txtid.Text & "%' "
                    Using command2 As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)
                        connection2.Open()
                        Dim i1 As Integer = command2.ExecuteScalar()
                        If i1 = 1 Then
                            MsgBox("ALREADY CLAIMED")
                        Else
                            Using connection3 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                                SQL = "Select Stub,Total,Brickham,Jamon,Fiesta,status from remaining_ham where Stub='" & txtclaim.Text & "'  and Emp_No LIKE'%" & txtid.Text & "%' "
                                Using myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection)
                                    Dim table = New DataSet
                                    myAdapter.Fill(table)

                                    txtbrick.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Brickham").ToString
                                    txtjamon.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Jamon").ToString
                                    txtfiesta.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Fiesta").ToString
                                    txttotal.Text = table.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Total").ToString

                                    If MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE?" + Environment.NewLine + "Stub No: " + txtid.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Brickham: " + txtbrick.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Jamon De Bola: " + txtjamon.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Fiesta Ham: " + txtfiesta.Text, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                                        'MsgBox("TAMA")
                                        jam = CDbl(txtjamon.Text)
                                        rmham = CDbl(txtremjamon.Text)
                                        txtremjamon.Text = (rmham - jam).ToString
                                        Dim dbjam = Format(CDbl(txtremjamon.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbjam = "" Then
                                            dbjam = 0
                                        End If

                                        brk = CDbl(txtbrick.Text)
                                        rembrk = CDbl(txtrembrick.Text)
                                        txtrembrick.Text = (rembrk - brk).ToString
                                        Dim dbbrick = Format(CDbl(txtrembrick.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbbrick = "" Then
                                            dbbrick = 0
                                        End If

                                        fiesta = CDbl(txtfiesta.Text)
                                        rmfiesta = CDbl(txtremfiesta.Text)
                                        txtremfiesta.Text = (rmfiesta - fiesta).ToString
                                        Dim dbfiesta = Format(CDbl(txtremfiesta.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbfiesta = "" Then
                                            dbfiesta = 0
                                        End If
                                        total = CDbl(txttotal.Text)
                                        rmtotal = CDbl(txtremtotal.Text)
                                        txtremtotal.Text = (rmtotal - total).ToString
                                        Dim dbtotal = Format(CDbl(txtremtotal.Text), "#,###")
                                        If dbtotal = "" Then
                                            dbtotal = 0
                                        End If

                                        Using connection4 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                                            SQL = "UPDATE order_ham SET rem_brick='" & dbbrick & "', rem_jam='" & dbjam & "', rem_fiesta='" & dbfiesta & "', rem_total='" & dbtotal & "' where Emp_No=" & txtid.Text & "  "
                                            Using command3 As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection4)
                                                connection4.Open()
                                                Dim i As Integer = command3.ExecuteNonQuery
                                                If i = 0 Then
                                                    MsgBox("WRONG")
                                                    Exit Sub
                                                Else
                                                    ' MsgBox("RIGHT")
                                                    Using connection5 As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
                                                        Dim date1 As Date = Date.Today
                                                        SQL = "UPDATE remaining_ham SET status='CLAIMED',ddate='" & DateTime.Now & "' where Stub='" + txtclaim.Text + "' and Emp_No LIKE '%" + txtid.Text + "%'  "
                                                        Using command4 As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection5)
                                                            connection5.Open()
                                                            Dim a As Integer = command4.ExecuteNonQuery
                                                            connection5.Close()
                                                            If a = 0 Then
                                                                MsgBox("not claim: ERROR ")
                                                                Exit Sub
                                                            Else
                                                                MsgBox("SUCCESS")
                                                                Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection5)
                                                                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                                                                    da.Fill(dt)
                                                                    MetroGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
                                                                    MetroGrid1.Rows.Clear()
                                                                    MetroGrid3.DataSource = Nothing
                                                                    MetroGrid3.Rows.Clear()
                                                                    loadRemainingHam()
                                                                    remainingorder()
                                                                    txtclaim.Focus()
                                                                End Using


                                                            End If


                                                        End Using
                                                    End Using

                                                End If
                                            End Using
                                        End Using




                                    Else
                                        MsgBox("CANCELLED")
                                    End If

                                End Using
                            End Using
                        End If

                    End Using
                End Using
            Else
                MsgBox("ERROR")
            End If

End Sub
```

The best thing you could do would be to put each query in a function. Also, parametrize everything!

```
Private Function GetClaimCount(ByVal id As String, ByVal claim As String) As Integer

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
        ' id should be a parameter!!
        SQL = "SELECT count(*) from remaining_ham where Stub=@stub and Emp_No LIKE '%" & id & "%'"
        Using Command As New MySqlCommand(SQL, connection)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stub", claim)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim", "CLAIMED")
            Command.CommandText = SQL
            connection.Open()
            count = Command.ExecuteScalar
        End Using
    End Using

    Return count
End Function

Private Sub addstub()

    Dim count As Integer = GetClaimCount(txtid.Text, txtclaim.Text)

    If count = 1 Then
        MsgBox("PROCESSING")
        ' ...
    Else
        MsgBox("ERROR")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: already tried that but the the main reason why it become too many connection because the server said it so. again, the programs that are using server db are also malfunctioning. How can I remove connections on the sql server?